# Which websites provide real-time updated Jupyter notebooks for Python teaching?

Tags: interactive-teaching

Often, I find it useful to teach some Python to students. In-person classes are easy in this regard, I can just go to [colab.research.google.com](https://colab.research.google.com/) and show them the concepts there. (It requires no technical knowledge to use it, that's why I prefer that over locally-run Jupyter notebooks.)

Despite the claim that it is good for collaborative working, it does *not* update live as I write content in those notebooks, as Google Jamboard would, for example.

Are there websites which provide Jupyter notebooks (with Python 3 backend) which I could use to work with students real-time? By real-time, I mean that I want my students to see what I have written in a cell within a second at least.

Comment: "Teaching Python" does not seem related to mathematics education.  Perhaps this question is better asked at [Computer Science Educators Stack Exchange](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it seems to be better asked at [Computer Science Educators Stack Exchange](https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: Oh, you have a point... I agree, that site would be a better fit. I mostly teach Python to students so they can do math-related things with it, that's why I saw it reasonable to post it here. Is there a way I can vote to migrate this question?

Comment: I've just raised a flag requesting the moderators to migrate this question.

Comment: It'll be simplest to just repost on the other site.

Comment: Done: https://cseducators.stackexchange.com/questions/7000/which-websites-provide-real-time-updated-jupyter-notebooks-for-python-teaching